# Persist session/cookies across successive get requests

Tags: cookies, get, rest-client

I am running a script that needs to execute several GET requests to an API using the RestClient gem.

However, this API needs cookies & session to be persisted in order to function properly.

I have this:

```
# first request
url = "http://example-api.com/first-endpoint?param1=foo&param2=bar
request = RestClient.get url, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
cookies = request.cookies

# second request
url = "http://example-api.com/second-endpoint?param1=foo&param2=bar
request = RestClient.get url, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
```

In order to make the second request work, I need to keep the same session and cookies. Using RestClient, I can send back the cookies in a POST request like this:

```
RestClient.post post_url, {}, {:cookies => cookies}
```

But I couldn't find in their documentation & on StackOverFlow any way to do this for a GET request.

How should I proceed to "keep" the cookies alive between two successive GET requests ? I'm also open to using another gem or technique if RestClient doesn't support this.

Any help will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this:

```
RestClient.get url,{:cookies => cookies}
```

And it seems to work fine !

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you want more fully fledged cookie support, in recent versions of rest-client (>= 2.0.0) you can use an actual cookie jar (`HTTP::CookieJar`), which behaves much more like a browser in following expiration / domain / path restrictions.

```
resp = RestClient.get(url)
jar = resp.cookie_jar

resp2 = RestClient::Request.execute(url: someurl, method: :get, cookies: jar)
```